# STOP auto adding space after colon on css properties

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

Yes, I know, according to someone's criteria this is more readable.

In our case it is NOT and we have programmed like this for years and we do not want to change it.

How can I disable that when I add a CSS property with auto-completion, it puts a space after the colon?

If I write, for example "flo", and I press enter to fill the "float" property, visual will put "float: ;" and I want it to write "float:;".

I have to remove space every single time and it's really struggling.

Thank you.

Search, configuration etc... NOTHING WORKS

Comment: I think the answer might be no. These settings tend to be of the form `css.format.*space*`. The only setting I see like that is `css.format.spaceAroundSelectorSeparator`.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work :(

Comment: ... yep... that's what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do what you want.  You are looking for an `emmet` preference. See [Emmet Preferences: v1.16 Release Notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_16#_emmet-preferences):

There is supposedly support for the `css.valueSeparator`, see also [GH Issue: Emmet Preferences support](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32496).

So you should be able to do this in your settings:

```
"emmet.preferences": {
    "css.valueSeparator": ":",
}
```

The default for `css.valueSeparator` appears to be `:` , see [Emmet Preferences](https://docs.emmet.io/customization/preferences/).

BUT, it doesn't work for me for some reason - seems like some completion option is not respecting the `css.valueSeparator` setting.  So you may have better luck - or need to file a github issue on this.

Comment: It seems that this configuration is correct.
And it partly works: If autocompletes including value of property eg: left for float, it does write "float:left", 

But if autocompletes only with the name, it still puts the damn space after the colon.

Thank you.